# In a bash script what means < $1 >

Tags: bash, shell, shell-exec

in a bash script what means `< $1 >` ? It means that the file is opened to read from it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at any shell reference material? The answer to this question is not hard to find.

Comment: `<` = redirect file as input, `$1` = argument #1 for the script. `>` = redirect output to file.

Comment: Removed PowerShell tag.

Comment: You should post some context. `< $1 >` alone is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` is the first parameter after the name of the script.

If you call a script like this: `myscript.sh param1 param2`

- `$0` will be `myscript.sh`
- `$1` will be `param1`
- `$2` will be `param2`
- ...

Comment: And `command <$1 >foo` means run `command` with input from the file named as the first argument to the script, and output written to `foo`.  The `<` input redirection is associated with `$1` but the output redirection with `>` and another file name is a separate, distinct construct.